# Finding a path to a File given it's ID

Tags: google-drive-api

I get a FileList with:

```
    String q = "title contains '"+query+"' and trashed = false";
    FileList list = drive.files().list().setQ(q).execute();
```

I want to find a path to each matching file in the FileList.

I understand that the same File can appear in multiple Folders.

From what I've found, the only way to create a path for a File is to repeatedly call:

```
    drive.files().get(id).execute()
```

and then choose an ID from that File's parents list, walking up the tree until the root is reached.

While navigating the tree, I could just choose the first parent, or do a "BFS" until I find the root.

Is this really the only way to find a path to a File, or have I missed some part of the API?

If this is the only way, can Folders have multiple parents, too, making cycles possible?

(/a/b/c => /a/b/c/b/c/b/c... if b has parents a & c)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since folders (which are simply special Drive File with a specific MIME type) can have multiple parents, I would recommend the BFS approach and making sure you handle loops.

For the stop condition, you can save the root folder's ID that you can retrieve from the [about.rootFolderId](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#rootFolderId) attribute.

Comment: Does the parentReference have a title field? Ultimately I need to end up with a list of path elements, not File IDs.

Comment: I see, in this case, you can't use drive.parents.list. I update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Alain, do you know if it's necessary to use about.rootFolderId, or is an empty parents list sufficient? If about.rootFolderId is required, can this ever change within an account, or can I cache it permanently?

Comment: Unfortunately, the lack of parent cannot be used as files can be outside of the root folder (e.g hidden/archived). The root folder ID should never change within an account and you could also send a `GET` request to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root` to retrieve the root folder's metadata.

Comment: This is a real problem for me. The BFS approach is very slow. I want the path as it would appear in my local filesystem. Surely that doesn't allow multiple parents? I couldn't see how I could add multiple parents to a folder in Google Drive.